# How do I get consecutive same input to break loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, break

I am trying to make a student credit calculator. It must display the text:  `You did have too many study breaks` when the user inputs 0 twice in a row. Code should also end there. I have no idea to even begin solving this problem, but I have the rest of the code ready.

```
def main():

    months=int(input("Enter the number of months: "))
    total=0

    for i in range(months):
        points=float(input("Enter the number of credits in month {}: ".format(i+1)))
        total += points

    average=total/months
    if average >= 5:
        print(f"You are a full time student and your monthly credit point average is {average:.1f}")
    elif average < 5:
        print(f"Your monthly credit point average {average:.1f} does not classify you as a full time student.")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So to clarify, if user inputs 0 in points twice in a row, the loop should break and the text be displayed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a new variable to count duplicates, and the add an "if sentence" where the if sentence ends with "break"

```
def main():

    //counter
    duplicates = 0

    months=int(input("Enter the number of months: "))
    total=0

    for i in range(months):
        points=float(input("Enter the number of credits in month {}: ".format(i+1)))

        //Add checks if it is a duplicate, if there are 2 or more duplicate, end 
        //for sentence

        if points == 0:
            duplicates += 1
        else:
            duplicates = 0

       if duplicates >= 2:
            break

        total += points

    average=total/months
    if average >= 5:
        print(f"You are a full time student and your monthly credit point average is {average:.1f}")
    elif average < 5:
        print(f"Your monthly credit point average {average:.1f} does not classify you as a full time student.")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Only one more problem: now if I type the last two inputs as 0, I get the average not the "too many study breaks" text. So for instance if i type 3 months as 3,0,0 I should get the "too many study breaks" text

Comment: You can add an local "check = False" and say "check = True" before the break. Then at the average if sentence write "if avrage >= 5 and not check: ....". Or you could just change the break to "return print("too many study breaks")"

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the previous input:

```
prev = -1
for i in range(months):
    points=float(input("Enter the number of credits in month {}: ".format(i+1)))
    if not (prev or points):
        break
    total += points
    prev = points
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to keep track of the previous value from the last input. Then check this "prev" variable and compare to your "current" variable on each iteration. It is important to set this "prev" value BEFORE you get your new input.

If they are both equal, you know that the user entered the same input consecutively.

**Example:**

```
def main():

    months=int(input("Enter the number of months: "))
    total=0
    prev=0
    data = 0

    for i in range(months):
        prev = data
        data = input("Enter the number of credits in month {}: ".format(i+1))
        if ((prev==data) && data == 0): 
            print("You have too many study breaks")
            break

        points=float(data)
        total += points

    average=total/months
    if average >= 5:
        print(f"You are a full time student and your monthly credit point average is {average:.1f}")
    elif average < 5:
        print(f"Your monthly credit point average {average:.1f} does not classify you as a full time student.")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with the end if needed function already in it:

```
def main():
    pointsEnd = 0
    months=int(input("Enter the number of months: "))
    total=0

    for i in range(months):
        points=float(input("Enter the number of credits in month {}: ".format(i+1)))
        if points == 0: #here is the new code
            pointsEnd += 1
            if pointsEnd == 2:
                end = print('You did have too many study breaks')
                return end
                ()
        total += points

    average=total/months
    if average >= 5:
        print(f"You are a full time student and your monthly credit point average is {average:.1f}")
    elif average < 5:
        print(f"Your monthly credit point average {average:.1f} does not classify you as a full time student.")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hey, it seems this code is breaking the loop even if the zeros arent in a row. Thanks for the help still.